# Cannot connect Django to existing MySQL database on M1 mac

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, apple-m1

**UPDATE**: I found a solution and possible cause; posted an answer with steps to make it work below.

So, I am having trouble connecting Django to an existing MySQL database (created from a dump for dev purposes). Here is my steps and all the terminal output:
[image]

### Get database ready

1. [Install MySql 5.7](https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21)
2. Start MySQL `brew services start mysql@5.7`
3. Open MySQL Workbench and connect via password
4. Create new schema
   [image]
5. Open MySQL Database dump; insert `use climate` at the top of file, run script -> Database is ready

### Setting up Django

- create new python venv `python3 -m venv good-env`
- Activate venv `source good-env/bin/activate`
- Installing django `python -m pip install Django`

```
Downloading Django-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 7.9 MB 3.8 MB/s 
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
 Using cached sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.3.2
 Using cached asgiref-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pytz
 Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, asgiref, pytz, Django
Successfully installed Django-3.2.2 asgiref-3.3.4 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

- Creating a project `django-admin startproject climatevisual`; `cd climatevisual`

### Connecting Django with the database

- Installing [required drivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) (I know only mysqlclient should suffice, but that led to the same result so I started trying to install both...)

  - `pip install mysqlclient`

```
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.0.3
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

- `pip install mysql-connector-python`

```
Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Using cached mysql_connector_python-8.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (319 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.0.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.15.8-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting six>=1.9
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, protobuf, mysql-connector-python
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.24 protobuf-3.15.8 six-1.16.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

- editing climatevisual/settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'climate',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

- auto generating the models `python manage.py inspectdb`
  **THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/aaronkurz/Dev/2/good-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

If this step would have worked; I would next have followed/finished [the tutorial here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/).

I have already tried countless things,

- reinstalling MySQL,
- using the newest version of MySQL (even though I had to edit the DB dump then and it would not be possible in the real project since the project needs this version of MySQL)
- I have tried the solution the OP of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109987/nameerror-name-mysql-is-not-defined-after-setting-change-to-mysql) proposed
- also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940297/django-connect-mysql-problem-nameerror-name-mysql-is-not-defined)
- also [this answer](also [this answer]) (and many more tbh)

Does somebody have a clue what is going wrong here?

If it helps: I am running macOS 11.3.1.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are all of the underscores in the code preceded by a blackslash?  How did that happen?

Comment: @JohnGordon I literally don't know; I copied it out of the Terminal app into an md editor to here. That was the default behauvior of the Terminal app. I had to change the copy behaviour of Terminal to disable it via Edit>Copy Special>Plain Text. I think I edited it and fixed it in the question now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem! I think the problem is that there are some compatibility issues between the MySQLdb module and the M1 mac I am using. But I could connect the database and import the model using [PyMySQL](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/) instead!
The steps I took are the following:

- Change my settings.py database section to this:

```
import pymysql
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'climate',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
# Fake PyMySQL's version and install as MySQLdb
# https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 2, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

- run `pip install pymysql
- then run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`
- then run `python manage.py migrate`

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I found there is an issue using pymysql because my Django project is using JSONField and the app is crashing with error that it requires MySQL 5.7+ version, even when my MySQL server version is 8.1. However I found that mysql-connector-python solves this for me. Run:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

to get the module installed and configure your DATABASES like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
     # Rest of your configuration
  }
}
```

This seems to fix all issues with working with MySQL in Django on Mac Silicon processors.